# Ubuntu VM is responding very slow

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine, virtualization

I have installed Oracle VM Box in my windows 10 machine and loaded Ubuntu 18 as guest OS. But when I boot my VM box, the Ubuntu OS responding fast for few mins, then it slows down and taking too much time even if i open any text file.

I have configured 2cpu and 2GB ram for that machine, 64bit OS.

Kindly someone help to fix this issue.

Comment: What size is the swap file in your VM? 2GB RAM is not a huge amount (although only 1gB is recommended), so depending on what you are doing, Ubuntu might need more and use the swap file

Comment: My swap memory showing 470total and 420mb free. I am running only the docker engine in tha VM. When I am executing any docker commands, its taking time to respond even normal ps command.